# Wiped from Memory

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Can anyone help with the name and any details on this short story?

It concerns a genius inventor. He invents, for instance, a drink that slows down time that he takes and then wanders the streets watching the vast amount of time something like a fly will take to cross a room.

He then invents a very dangerous technique where he can send another person in a group out of this existence and obliterate all memory of that person. He tells a group of people, mainly his friends, about this invention and goaded by their disbelief, sets the invention in motion.

I'm not sure how its supposed to work (it's been at least sixty years since I read the story) but all the people in the group are described including one shy man or woman. They close their eyes, the process starts. When they wake, there is general relief that all is the same. Getting up to leave, someone knocks over an empty chair.

It's a classic 'twist in the tail' ending and you realise that any memory of the outsider is wiped from memory.

The clever paradox is that the inventor will always believe that his invention is a failure.

Comment: What's the earliest "definitely-no-later-than" date you can put on reading the story? 1960?

Comment: I would have read this story in the 1950's.

Comment: I love a challenging paradox! In this case, no matter how many times the inventor sends people off into the wide, blue yonder, it will always seem as though his invention was a failure. it might be argued that the existence of an empty chair is evidence that someone was once there, but I suspect that if every memory of a person could be wiped out, then any clue to their original existence would also be wiped out, perhaps by sending the chair as well into oblivion or otherwise ensuring any group members doesn't follow the clue. No wonder we call it speculative fiction!

Comment: It's not the one you're looking for, but you might enjoy "Thus We frustrate Charlemagne" by R. A. Lafferty. You can read it for free at https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v25n03_1967-02#page/n125/mode/2up

Comment: The first story you describe looks very much like *The New Accelerator* by H. G. Wells; the name of the scientist is Professor Gibberne and he involves a close friend.

Comment: Why not just write "there are four people in this group. Yes really. We double checked. Here are the names:..." on a note?

Comment: I don't understand. If you know there were four people in the group, what is the name of the story and the author. I can't recall how many people were in the group over sixty years after reading the story. Sounds like a strong lead.

Comment: There are some similarities in this to something I answered yesterday - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180864/title-of-a-short-story-where-an-old-man-completely-eliminates-all-trace-of-a-you . Not all details line up, but I think it could still be the story you were looking for.

Comment: @TakeruDavis I have the short story. The introduction doesn't match, but the rest of the story is a perfect match to Exit by Harry Fargeon. I think you should post that as an answer here, or I can do it if you want.

Comment: @John Rennie I did now. Due to the difference, I was not completely certain if it is really the same story.

Comment: @JohnRennie What anthology do you have Harry Farjeon's "Exit" in? Does it also have "The Ruum" and "Tickets, Please" as asserted by the asker of that other question?

Comment: I have the story as a pdf, not in an anthology. I did look on ISFDB but I can't see an anthology containing *The Ruum* and *Exit*. Actually I can't see an anthology containing *The Ruum* and *Tickets, please*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on striking similarities between this and [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180864/title-of-a-short-story-where-an-old-man-completely-eliminates-all-trace-of-a-you) I answered yesterday, I would suggest trying **Exit** by *Harry Farjeon*.

The main difference is the guy is not an inventor, he just seems to have some special power and he probably knows it works, but otherise it's a perfect match, the question did also mention empty chair getting knocked over.

Answer (score 4):

The first half of your description (an inventor coming up with a drink that slows down time for him) sounds like the plot of H.G. Wells's [The New Accelerator](http://www.online-literature.com/wellshg/16/).

Comment: Hi, and welcome!  Nice catch, this part of the question wasn't covered in the existing answer.  You could improve your question by adding some quotes from the source that match the details of the question.  That would improve its searchability, and provide a fallback in case of link rot.