# Short story where an old man completely eliminates all trace of a young woman's existence

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

In the 1980s I read a short story in an anthology that also contained "The Ruum" by Arthur Porges and "Tickets Please" by D H Lawrence. The short story featured a group of possibly British people staying at a hotel. An old man claimed he could make anyone disappear totally, so that no one would even remember they had ever existed (no photos, physical evidence, memories of the person, etc.). No one believes him so he does it, and the story ends with a young newly wed man kicking over a stool that his bride (Jessamy?) had been sitting on, but she is no longer there, so she was the one who was totally eliminated. But no one believes the old man actually did what he claimed because no one could remember the young woman having been there, not even her new husband. I always found it a bit chilling and creepy, but can't remember what the story was called.

Comment: I wonder if this is the same as [Wiped from Memory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169732/wiped-from-memory)

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205888/short-story-about-a-man-betting-a-group-he-could-tell-a-story-and-one-of-them-w (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 15):

It was a little tricky to pinpoint, but the effect of the powers described is on TV Tropes called [Ret Gone](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RetGone). At first, after reading through their list of literature containing this trope, I thought it wasn't there.

But then I noticed the last entry, which lacked the usual summary and decided to look it up elsewhere. And there it was.

I believe what you are looking for is [**Exit** by *Harry Farjeon*](https://web.archive.org/web/20160222090606/https://kingstonhighschool1.wikispaces.com/file/view/Short+Story+-+Exit+by+Harry+Farjeon.pdf).

> Mr Geeles: ... He is old, on his own, has not joined into anything, has special powers...
>
> Jessamy: young woman who should not have been decreated as she had done no wrong. She was in love, frightened of whole process. Mr Geeles selected her as he could not stand to see the young couple happy. Nobody notices he has been decreated even her husband.

---[Source](http://web.archive.org/web/20111221071839/http://mrsyacameron.wikispaces.com/Exit+essay+plan)

Comment: That TV Tropes page has a link to [the film adaptation](https://vimeo.com/76992293).

Comment: The old man did not meanly pick on Jessamy because she was happy. He told the group that once the process began, the choice was out of his hands. It would have been ironic if he had been chosen. No one would have remembered the experiment had taken place.

Comment: @StephenCollicoat I agree, I only quoted the summary written by someone else

Comment: Doing a bit of research...  There's no "Harry Farjeon" recorded in ISFDB.  There is a composer by that name, but none of his works appear to be SF. :)  None of the contributors with last name "Farjeon" listed in [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=farjeon&type=Name) have written a story named "Exit."  If all the evidence is a TVTropes entry with no canonical links, I wonder if this even exists?

Comment: Or maybe ISFDB has a gap in it's informations, just try to use Google.

[Here's a discussion about the story](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/cellofun/exit-by-harry-farjeon-t16251.html) mentioning it supposedly was written by the musician. Perhaps it was included in a collection published by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was "Exit" in a book of short stories.  It ends with the vacant chair being kicked over and the participants thinking it hadn't worked.

Comment: Can you provide any more details? Like the author, a link to a summary? Etc...

Comment: This seems to be the same as the existing answer.