# Short story about a man betting a group he could tell a story, and one of them would disappear and the others would not notice

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In about 1966 or so, a stand-in teacher at our primary school spent the afternoon reading short stories to us. There was a wide genre, but I was particularly fond a one which was science fiction/mystery.

It involved a group of people who were talking about mysteries, and another man from outside the group bet the he could tell a story, and one of them would disappear and the others would not notice. The final line was something like "he kicked over the stool and walked from the room".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wiped from Memory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169732/wiped-from-memory)

Comment: @BjornEriksson The OP has not accepted the answer and so this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Another possible duplicate https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180864/title-of-a-short-story-where-an-old-man-completely-eliminates-all-trace-of-a-you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This sounds like [**Exit** by Harry Farjeon](https://web.archive.org/web/20160222090606/https://kingstonhighschool1.wikispaces.com/file/view/Short+Story+-+Exit+by+Harry+Farjeon.pdf) (adapted into a [film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2034679/) in 2012)

It involves a group of people attending a dinner party including a newly-wed couple by the names of Jake and Jessamy. Mr Geeles claims he can erase people from existence, referred to as "de-creation" in the story. Of course no one believes he can do this, as the de-created are also wiped from all memory of ever having existed. He ends up trying to demonstrate his claim. At the end an empty footstool is kicked over where Jessamy had been sat.

Comment: Yes, Exit by Harry Farjeon. Here it is as a short film. [https://vimeo.com/76992293](https://vimeo.com/76992293) Just watched it. Quality acting. But I find the story one-dimensional.

Comment: The book in question does indeed appear to be *Exit*, the line quoted in the question being "Jake stretched, and kicked the footstool aside." where the footstool had once been occupied by another member of their group. The source can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160222090606/https://kingstonhighschool1.wikispaces.com/file/view/Short+Story+-+Exit+by+Harry+Farjeon.pdf and does appear to be a legitimate source of the text itself.

Comment: This story seems strangely hard to find. It's not listed in ISFDB. It doesn't seem to be at Project Gutenberg even though there's a good chance based on age that it's out of copyright. The author's Wikipedia page (assuming that the composer is the same person) doesn't mention it. However, I'm pretty sure that I read this in a print collection at some point. Weird.

Comment: ISFDB does accept submissions, so if we ever find the information, it's remediable.

Comment: Ah, you guys are great. It is indeed "Exit". Thank you so much for solving this question for me. Shane

Comment: Which is of course the same basic idea as R A Lafferty’s much earlier story “Thus We Frustrate Charlemagne”.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a stretch, but could it be *Child of an Ancient City* by Tad Williams?
This short book is about a group of men who are being stalked by a vampire in the woods as they travel. Eventually, the vampire gives them an ultimatum: If he can tell a story sadder than any story they tell, he gets to take one member of their party, then he will leave them alone.
The book is essentially a conglomeration of short stories, as the men attempt to tell the saddest story, but in the end the vampire wins by telling a true story of his own life, and how he became a vampire. However, when one of the men volunteers to be the one taken, the vampire leaves without a trace.